# Terminal server - disconnect possible if no client activity, but file transfer

Tags: terminal-server, timeout, file-transfer

We are testing a file transfer script that is started through a client session on a terminal server - the client is Ubuntu rdesktop. What we find is that the session is disconnected after a while, even though the file transfer is still running.

Is this a time out setting in Terminal server or likely another problem. Note that we probably don't have any "client activity", only the file transfer is running. It is a simple file copy to a locally mounted drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a timeout on the terminal server.  Activity qualifies as keyboard or mouse input.

If you do not want to increase this server-wide, it can be increased on a per-user account basis on the Sessions tab of the user account.

[image]